# stop video when close modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

I am facing an issue with my modal with video, when i close the modal the video is still playing on the background i haven't any clue.

Can someone help me out here to stop video from playing when i close the modal?

my js

```
<script>
    function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
        if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('popup-wrapper').style.display = "none";
        else document.getElementById('popup-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            PopUp('show');
        }, 100);
    }
    </script>
```

here is the video part

```
<div id="popup-wrapper" style='display:none'>
    <div id="popup">
    <a href="#modal-close" class="modal-close" onClick="PopUp('hide')">X CLOSE</a>   
    <h1>HOW IT WORKS?</h1>   

   <div class="form-group">
      <video width="100%" controls>
        <source src="vdo.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
        <source src="vdo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the modal select the `video` element and call `pause()` on it.

```js
function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
  if (hideOrshow == 'hide') {
    document.getElementById('popup-wrapper').style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector('video').pause(); // add this
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('popup-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
  }
}
```

Also note that given `hideOrShow` only has two states it would make more sense to use a boolean value.

Comment: unable to get it work still plays. could you show me on my code how to correctly do it?  Appreciate it

Comment: Try the `pause()` method instead of `stop()`

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Comment: @Sherline note that this pauses the video at the current time. To 'stop' it (play again from the beginning) have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs#Stopping_the_video